# When you double click an application at OS level

Tags: operating-system, window

> What happens when we double click an application at OS level. I understand that this is highly OS dependent. But i think that in windows

The currently executing process will fork() a new child process and the Process Control Block of the newly created child process will be initialized with the data required for the application and the new process would be scheduled or would be executed immediately

Any suggestions.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Like fork() on linux , we have CreateProcess on windows. Similarly all the initialization will happen ... for more details you can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx. Like in linux we use command ps to list the running processes , here in windows we have tasklist.